# Extreme Value Theorem on Logistic Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification, extreme-value-theorem

Let $_1,_2, … , _$ be a random sample of size  from a distribution with cumulative distribution function $F() = \frac{1}{1 + \exp(-cx)}$, $−\infty <  < \infty$, where $ > 0$. Let $_ = \max(X_1,X_2, \dots , X_n)$ and $Z_n = Y_n - $ log $n$. Show that $Z_$ converges in distribution to a random variable with cumulative distribution function of $(Z) = \exp(−\exp(−)) , −\infty < Z < \infty$.

I think that it is impossible to prove it unless $Z_n = Y_n - \frac{1}{c}$ log $n$ or if $c=1$?

Comment: @john22445: Perhaps you want to add the reference (if this is a problem from a book) to list it as an errata for the author or for the community.

Answer (score 0):

We have that
$$\mathbb{P}(Z_n \leq x) = \mathbb{P}(\max(X_1, \dots, X_n) + \log n \leq x) = \mathbb{P}(\max(X_1, \dots, X_n) \leq x + \log n) = \\
\mathbb{P}(X_1 \leq x + \log n, \dots, X_n \leq x + \log n) = (F(x + \log n))^n$$
since the $X_i's$ are iid. Thus the cdf of $Z_n$ is
$$G_n(x) = (1 + \exp(-c(x + \log n)))^{-n} = (1 + n^{-c} \exp(-c x))^{-n} = \\
\big((1 + n^{-c} \exp(-c x))^{n^c \exp(c x)}\big)^{- \exp(- c x) n^{1 - c}}.$$
Of course, the quantity inside the big brackets will converge to $e$ as $n \to \infty,$ but we run into problems with the exponent. However, retracing our steps with your proposed formula for $Z_n = Y_n - \frac{1}{c} \log n,$ we find
$$G_n(x) = \big((1 + \frac{1}{n} \exp(-c x))^{n \exp(c x)}\big)^{- \exp(- c x)},$$
which will of course converge to $G(x) = \exp(- \exp(- c x))$ as desired. I hope this helps. :)

Comment: it seems like you are on my side too, the question might have error

Comment: Yes, that is what I proved, the original statement is erroneous, whereas the one you proposed is correct and yields the desired convergence in distribution. Please do consider accepting the answer if it was of help to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP is in the right.

Let $Z_n=\max_{1\leq j\leq n}Y_j -\frac{1}{c}\log n$.

Notice that
\begin{align}
F_{Z_n}(x)&=\mathbb{P}\big[\max_{1\leq j\leq n}Y_n\leq x+\frac{\log n}{c}\big]=\Big(F_{Y_1}\big(x+\frac{\log n}{c}\big)\Big)^n=\frac{1}{(1+e^{-c(x+\frac{\log n}{c})})^n}\\
&=\frac{1}{\Big(1+\frac{e^{-cx}}{n}\Big)^n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{-e^{-cx}}
\end{align}
Since $F(x)=e^{-{e^{cx}}}$ is the distribution of a Borel probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$ , it follows that $Z_n$ converges in law (aka in distribution) to a random variable $Z$ whose distribution is  given by $F$ (Helly-Bray theorem).

If $Z'_n:=\max_{1\leq j\leq n}Y_j - \log n$, then
$$F_{Z'_n}(x)=\frac{1}{\big(1+\frac{e^{-cx}n^{1-c}}{n}\big)^n}$$
which converges to $1$ if $1-c<0$ and to $0$ if $c-1>0$. In the former case $Z'_n$ losses all mass at $-\infty$ and in the latter $Z'_n$ losses all mass at $+\infty$; in either case, $Z'_n$ does not converge in distribution to any probability measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$.